# 底上げする - why do we need it?

Tags: verbs, anime

Can you please help me understand the title giving verb?

According to dictionaries it means "rasing the bottom" or "raising the standard".

I found it in the fourth episode of Swordart Online at 5:30.
The protagonist gives away some items to a women claiming they will raise her level.

But why can't he use the normal 挙げる/上げる or something like 増す?

The full sentence is:
それなら５－６レベルは底上げできる。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick look at episode for more context: main character give another player powerful equipment in order to travel with him to a high-level dungeon.

底上げ is used here as raising the bottom standard. The main character is comparing the girl to him (since he already plans to go with her), so he is raising the "bottom" of his party. You cannot use レベルアップ or レベルを上げる here, as the items do not level up the character (they are just armor), they only boost the girl's stats several level's worth. It probably would have have been more accurate if he said 「５，６レベル分を底上げ出来る (you can boost your (stats) 5-6 level's worth)」, but it's still understandable to a native speaker.

Imagine if you had five people in my party in an RPG: three were level 20 and two were level l1. If I were to 底上げ, I would  focus on leveling up/buying equipment for the level 11s so they would catch up to the higher leveled characters, which is basically what the main character did in the scene.

Comment: Thanks a lot answers my question perfectly 